# How to display multiple images on mouse hover on php

Tags: php, css, onmouseover

i am writing a php download portal script. i want to add multiple images as thumbnail on mouse hover. just like this http://www.urokitv.ru when i put mouse on a video, its showing pictures from a folder serially. 1.jpg then 2.jpg then 3.jpg then 4.jpg .... now i want to do that on a php for my script. suppose my file name is myfile.ext so i put thumbnail for this file on thumb folder. so my code for display this on page is

now i want to show thumbnails one by one when mouse hover on it. i want to show more then one picture on mousehover. How can i show multiple images on mouse hover in php? i dont know how to ask much better a question, if my question is not enough specific.

Comment: This is not possible by means of php. You need client side logic for that, so JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing this by using HTML and JavaScript statements within ECHO.

Either you run a LOOP in PHP that would replace your echo statement containing new image after certain interval OR you may use JQuery to easily do it.